# Compatibility of JBehave and Cucumber with Java 11

Tags: cucumber, java-11, jbehave

I am successfully using Java 8 with JBehave. Now I would like to switch to Java 11, but find no information about the JBehave compatibility.

Using Cucumber instead would also be possible, but here I only found news from 2/2019 saying that Cucumber is only partially compatible.

Does anybody have experiences with Java 11 and one of these BDD tools?

Answer (score 0):

JBehave 4.5.1 is fully compatible with Java 11.

I've successfully been using latest JBehave versions with Java 9, 10, 11. No Java-specific issues are found.